# Route issue in Node JS with express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a godaddy domain being redirected to an instance of EC2 with an elastic IP. on instance there runs my NodeJS on port 5000. i m redirecting 80 to 5000( till here everything works fine). In express i have a route say '/Calculate/:Type', which is visited when some caculate button is pressed. ideally the when button is pressed a request to server should go like http://example.com/calculate/3 but here is goes http://example.com//calculate/3 an extra / before caculate ruins the entire route. can someone please tell me why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a period in front of /Calculate/:Type so

`'./Calculate/:Type'` in your express route

Ahh so it seems like you may be hitting a CORS error. Is your webserver and dataserver on the same url?

- Best option : Put the node instance serving your app on yourdomain.com, and make your api endpoint api.yourdomain.com/Calculate/:Type
- Other Option: exposing yourself to security risks by adding a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *' in the header of your response
- Other Option: expose yourself to security change your settings in htaccess to allow all, or the specific domain

Comment: I doesnt work as there is another issue that i notice which is **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://beprodigy.com/Calculate/3. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://<ip of my ec2instance>' is therefore not allowed access.**   to avoid this i m using **cors** pakcage in npm still that doesnt resolve the problem. Although adding '.' to the route on the server doesnt help.

Comment: edited my answer - best option is to move your data point api to a subdirectory IMO

Answer (score 0):

Modify the route where you define the findone query and remove the forward slash from it.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?